# What does this mean in (what I think) is a function?

Tags: functions

[image: http://origin-ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0020025506001150-si78.gif]

This image. The curly bracket (some form of matrix)? What is it? How would I use it? I would find the meaning some other way, but I don't even know what to look up.

Comment: This is not a matrix, it is "definition by cases" (and yes, in LaTeX the command is \begin{cases}. That is, at each line is given a formula which defines the value of the defined function for __some of the arguments__, like in the first case, first line is value if argument is an even integer, second line is value in all other cases (from context, probably here it means "odd integers".

Answer (score 3):

The first function evaluates to $0.5$ if $n$ is even and to $0.2$ otherwise, that is what the notation means. For example, $\zeta (2)=0.5$ and $\zeta (3)=0.2$.

Comment: I get that. But what does '0.5' or '0.2' mean?

Comment: But what do they MEAN. Now, let's say, in the second function, I have μ(12). Since 12 is even, does μ(12) = 0.7? Sorry, I am very new to this.

Comment: Yes $\mu(12)=0.7$ and also $\mu(42)=0.7$ whereas $\mu(1729)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was very confused about this. I am appreciative of your help, both of you.